# Cities/Province/Cantons list with coords?

Tags: python, database, geolocation, coordinates, gis

where can I get a list of that? I need the coords of the distrits and cantons of Costa Rica, is there a place to get those?

thanks in advance

Comment: **coords of the distrits and cantons** - do you mean the borderlines or just central points?

Comment: central points, borderlines it's possible?

Comment: Not a programming question. Just because a list may be used in code doesn't make it a programming question.

Comment: i need the list to put into MySql Database, maybe for that i put here! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/) is a public database of all cities/towns with a population over 1000. The data for each city includes geo coordinates and administrative division, which I believe would be your districts, provinces or cantons.

Comment: i'm not from CR, i have the list of geonames, the problem is that the list is unordered with around of 4500 lines and i don't how can i order only that i'm interested.

Comment: @eos87: the exact format of the database is described in http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt - you'll have to parse it, keep only the lines where the country code is CR and perhaps map every line to a python object. Then do whatever you need.

Comment: +1 for the link.  @eos87 - just like the one on the link I provided in my answer, this is a tab-separated file.  To order it, there are many possible options.  One it to use an import wizard to import it into a database, or Excel.. Or you can just read it - most programming languages have a way of reading a CSV for TSV file like a database table.

Comment: hey @Michael thanks for you help, it work for me, I cleaned it with OpenOffice calc and i have a CSV file to put my DB. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Costa Rica link [here](http://earth-info.nga.mil/gns/html/country_files.html) - it may suit your needs.

I found it with this search:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=%22costa+rica%22+%2Bgeocode+database&form=QBRE&qs=n&sk=&sc=1-31

Since you're using Python, you can read it using the csv module as described here: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/csv/

Answer (score 0):

The link left by David is to the National Geospatial-Intelligenace Agency (NGA) GEONet Server. This only has geodata for foriegn countries. For the US and its dependencies, the geocode data is maintained by the USGS in the GNIS Server at:

http://geonames.usgs.gov/domestic/download_data.htm