# Existent geolocations list

Tags: database, dictionary, geolocation

I need a simple list of verified existent cities, states (streets and sights if possible, but not necessary). I tried to find some dictionary on the internet, like a plain text file or a web page, but it's hard to make good search query for that.
Or maybe there's a way to get this list from some maps API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed hard to make a good search query for that. I just clicked a related questions link and this might help:

http://www.geonames.org/

(copied from an answer on [Cities/Province/Cantons list with coords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961469/cities-province-cantons-list-with-coords))

They offer files for donwload and webservices.